# Overlapping Text in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working with SAP Crystal Report 2012. I am suppose to create a Crystal Report which may be exported to PDF. It has certain fields with "Can Grow" property. As a result of all this I am facing overlapping text issues due increase in the text length, I do not want to limit the length of text fields.

I have already tried keeping fields in the different sections. It did removed overlapping but it duplicated the fields as there is a grouping applied in these fields and thus hampered the whole format.

Here is the image of the required format with overlapping text:

[image]

Here is the result of applying sectioning on the report as I said it did removed sectioning but duplicated the fields:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just keep your original layout and do this. Put you pointer over the margin and drag it to the left to create a section under your growing field. In that way the field can grow pushing down the section below. See below picture[image].